# I want to show foods based on categories in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a database table **categories** having columns:

- Category_id
- CategoryName

And other table is **Food** with:

- Food_id
- FoodName
- Category_id

I want to show the food items according to category on webpage. 
I'm using laravel 5.2 and I'm newbie.

Comment: What you mean by 'according to category'? do you mean you want to retrieve only the foods within one category?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes I want if category is breakfast then only food items related to this category are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join those two tables and fetch the data, here is an example on how you do it without creating a model.

```
 $rows = DB::table('food')->select('food.food_id','food.foodName','categories.categoryName')->join('categories','categories.category_id','=','food.category_id')->where('categories.categoryName', '=', 'breakfast')->get();
```

you can remove the where('','','') part if you dont want to filter

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You would create models for Food and Category. See here for the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent 
If you then add relations between both models in those models you can just use Laravels lazy/eager loading to get your data.